# delete all associated child rows when delete the parent row in cakephp 3

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-3.0

I'm new at cake php framework , and i want to delete the row from database and it's associated rows from the child table too .
Now , I can only delete the parent row but without it's child rows ,

How can i delete all the rows associated .

and here's my function for the parent :

```
    public function delete($id = null) {
    $contractor = $this->Contractors->get($id);
        if ($this->Contractors->delete($contractor)) {

        $this->Flash->success(__('The contractor has been deleted.'));
    } 
    else {
        $this->Flash->error(__('The contractor could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
    }

    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
}
```

and here's the function for the child

```
 public function deleteSub($id = null) {
    // $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);

    $contractorAttachments = $this->Contractors->ContractorsAttachments->get($id);
       if($contractorAttachments->Contractors->ContractorsAttachments->delete($contractorAttachments))
    {
          $this->Flash->success(__('The contractor Attacments has been deleted.'));
    }
    else {
        $this->Flash->error(__('The contractor Attacments could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
    }

    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
}
```

But i need to delete the child rows indidiual or delete all the parent row and all the associated child rows .

Can anyone help me with that ?

Comment: Make the model dependent & use the cascade option https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/deleting-data.html#delete

Comment: If you control the DDL, it might work to add a cascade option to your foreign key constraints.